# how a object finds that its in an other object scope like 'using'

Tags: c#, .net, scope, hierarchy, using

Is there any way that an object in a using block , find that using object in runtime and dynamically
like this

```
using (var grandfather = new human())
{
   using (var father = new human())
   {
      using (var son = new human())
      {
           ....
      }
   }
}
```

Now I want (son find father) , ( father find grandfather) and so on ...
UPDATE:
without direct reference to parent
UPDATE:
consider this I can modify human class in any way

Comment: How about having a property called Parent?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, but I strongly suspect the answer is "no". Why don't you just pass the `grandfather` reference to the `human` constructor?

Comment: as I said , its dynamic and change in runtime, its going through many class and method , its just simple example to show what i want

Comment: Using statements actually get translated to a try-finally on compilation.

Comment: @Matthijs: I know , i just wondering if its possible

Comment: It's impossible without direct reference to the parent

Comment: i see no reason to do this, maybe you can explain why you want to do it. it looks like an antipattern. probably the problem is within organizing the data / missing a [data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure)?!

Comment: @Koryu: there is reason , I have a logger that log elapsed time for its using block ,it start stopwatch in ctor and stop on Dispose and log it. Now I want make it hierarchy for better see logs , also it is possible , just solved that,ill post answer tomarrow